# How to store data on product import success in database using Magento2?

Tags: magento2, import

I want to store product data wieh
import start time,
import end time,
Product name,
Product Sku,
Status,
Error
fields in my custom table

once data imported successfully.

Comment: Where would you want to store product data, as the data is already imported successfully? You should explain bit more what is the requirement and what is that you want to achieve?

Comment: I have edited my question @LAW

Comment: You importing data via CSV, or importing the DB?

Comment: I am importing my data via CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach which can be used is -

Try creating an observer using event - `catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after`

Trace the data that is being logged in the observer(you can also log the data). Then when you get array of data in the observer, fetch the necessary data and save data in the observer only or create your custom model, to do so or whichever method suits you the best.